# Cannot get the e-mail address for a user in Auth0 rule

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, auth0

I have an Auth0 rule set up that tries to send a user's email

```
function(user, context, callback) {
   const email = user.email;
   // Send e-mail to API server
   callback(null, user, context);
}
```

This code works for basic login and some Facebook accounts, but not all; I have the e-mail scope set up in both the Auth0 connection configuration and the e-mail permission allowed by the Facebook app settings.

Comment: Not all Facebook accounts *have* an email address, which is the likely cause for your issues. They permit signup with a mobile phone number instead of an email if desired, and users can also reject the user_email permission when authorizing your app. You should prompt the user for email if you don't get one from the API.

Comment: That was my first thought, but testing against the e-mail login of another member of my team gives the same problem. And he's definitely got a valid e-mail address since he logs in using that.

Comment: Did they reject the `user_email` permission scope? Check the Facebook API directly - `me/permissions` should show you which ones are granted, and `me?fields=email` should show what's being returned.